# unity can't build phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I try to print out for mobile in unity, I get this error, where am I going wrong?

error

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 12 seconds (12117 ms)
3 errors
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

my codes

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Touch touch;

    public int speedModifier;

    public void Updite()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                                                  transform.position.y,
                                                  transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier);
            
            
            }

        }


    }

}
```

## I got this error while printing my game to the phone

Comment: You need to read the details of the fail messages.

Answer (score 0):

maybe set Updite to Update. Unity does not compile on such errors. It may not allow you to build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why you can't export your game to your phone.

From your code I conclude that instead of `Updite()` you should use `Update()`.

Your correct code will be like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Touch touch;

    public int speedModifier;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                                                  transform.position.y,
                                                  transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier);
            
            
            }

        }


    }

}
```